# How do I add Headers Name in Modal LOV plug-ins

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm setting up a Modal LOV plugin and I want to Give the Header name into plugin with my sql query

```
select com_id r,
         com_name d,
         com_name "COMPANY",
         com_add "ADDRESS", 
         PHONE_NO "PHONE"
 from PH_COMPANY;
```

I expected the output of this Modal LOV display data with the Headers. But the Output is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this attribute?

[image]

Comment: Yes I had checked it.it's all ok but don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: are you able to provide a screenshot and confirm how it is 'wrong'?